# on refresh redirect to path in angular2

Tags: angular, angular4-router

Hi in my application if i refresh it is going to home page,I need to avoid this and want to redirect to particular desired path, Not able to find where to implement this like in routing or somewhere,Can anyone please help me.
my app.component file

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from "@angular/router";
import {AppService} from "../../services/app.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
    islogin: boolean = true;
    currentPage: string = '';
    constructor(
      private router: Router,
      public appService: AppService
    ) {
    }
  ngOnInit() {
      this.islogin = !this.islogin;
  }
}
```

Routing file:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
     {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
},
    {
        path: 'superuser-miscsuperusers',
        component: miscsuperusersComponent
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        component: LoginComponent
    },
{
    path: 'clients',
    component: ClientsComponent
}

];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes/*, { enableTracing: true }*/);
```

Comment: add your app routing file

Comment: @Sravan added my routing file

Comment: from which route you are refreshing, because if you hit a page which does not have its route in routes, it goes to login page, as you have given `path: '**'`

Comment: Generally, the `path: '**'` should be redirected to any notfound page

Comment: @Sravan if i refresh from 'superuser-miscsuperusers' path it is going to login page i have to avoid this and want to redirect to 'client ' path which ihave not mentioned in my routing file

Comment: can you add `miscsuperusersComponent`

Comment: @Sravan i am having almost 40 components, Wherever i refresh it will goes to login page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159022/discussion-between-sravan-and-sudhir-mn).

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to particular page from app.component.ts file. on launch or on load

```
//Decide the page based on your logic .
let link = ['/landingpage'];
this.router.navigate(link);
```

Here the problem is you will lose all temporary data on refresh so you should use some other storage to get back your old state of application ex : localstorage.